# How can I repeat this query 100 times?

Tags: sql, oracle

I have this query to generate a random number from one table

select DBMS_RANDOM.value as val
from c4_trt 
where rownum=1;

Now I want to generate 100 random numbers from this table.

Please note: I want to generate a random number from this specific table, not from dual. But I'm not sure if I can generate a random number from a specific table.

Thanks all!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You stated in your question that you did NOT want to see a solution that utilizes the Oracle's dual dummy table.  Unless your table already has 100 + records in the table you are selecting from I currently don't see a way for you to get 100 records showing random numbers unless you use Connect By Level.

Below I've provided TWO answers that would get you 100 Random Numbers in 100 Rows of output.  The FIRST example uses the dual table and Connect By Level using LEVEL to limit the rows `CONNECT BY LEVEL <= 100`.  The SECOND example uses rownum and limits the rows using `rownum <= 100`.

`Using the dual table`

```
SELECT LEVEL, floor(dbms_random.value(1,11)) AS rand_num /* Returns random numbers 1 thru 10 */
FROM dual
CONNECT BY LEVEL <= 100
;
```

`Using any other table`
This example uses Oracles all_objects Dictionary View as it returns way more than 100 Rows so I decided to work with this but know that any Table/View that returns more than 100 rows will work in this example.

```
SELECT floor(dbms_random.value(1,11)) AS rand_num, /* Returns random numbers 1 thru 10 */
       rownum as at_row_num
FROM all_objects
WHERE rownum <= 100
;
```

The Image below shows what the output looks like when using the dual table example.

[image]

Comment: thank you very much! yes, my table c4_trt has 10M rows, but i do want to get a random number generated from this table and repeat 100 times.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure why you need or want to but this will work if you have at least 100
rows in your table and that's only to keep rownum happy.  The table you use is irrelevant.

```
select DBMS_RANDOM.value as val from c4_trt where rownum =< 100;
```